# How to get the total number of documents in an index

Tags: go, elasticsearch

Used libraries:https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/olivere/elastic/v7

```
res, _ := orm.Es.Search("pk").Do(context.Background())
fmt.Println("res",res.TotalHits()) // output:10000
```

count: 3628800 The number queried is only 10,000, how to get the total?

Comment: Paginated results? You'll need to iterate through all pages to get the full tally.

Comment: Can it be calculated all at once? Similar: select count (*) from table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set `track_total_hits` search option to `true`.

> Generally the total hit count can’t be computed accurately without visiting all matches, which is costly for queries that match lots of documents. The `track_total_hits parameter` allows you to control how the total number of hits should be tracked. Given that it is often enough to have a lower bound of the number of hits, such as "there are at least 10000 hits", the default is set to 10,000. This means that requests will count the total hit accurately up to 10,000 hits. It’s is a good trade off to speed up searches if you don’t need the accurate number of hits after a certain threshold.
>
> When set to true the search response will always track the number of hits that match the query accurately

There is a [great article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.1/search-request-track-total-hits.html) from the official documentation describing what it is.

Enable it in your code by invoking `TrackTotalHits` method:

```
res, _ := orm.Es.Search("pk").TrackTotalHits(true).Do(context.Background())
```

Or, if you only need total count, just use [Count API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html):

```
res, _ := orm.Es.Count("pk").Do(context.Background())
```